# Python Thread Scheduling

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to implement a ThreadPool + Scheduler in Python 2.7 with the module Threading. My pool contains threads that are allocated up front, and my scheduler handles which thread should perform the task. I have some threads that execute a system process, and wait for the result of it. These system calls can take a very long time, and I was hoping to be able to reuse the thread while the task is executing.

Example:

1. ThreadPool has 8 threads
2. 8 tasks come in all together
3. 9th task comes in after a small delay
4. Task 1 takes 1024 years (Maybe it could use some optimization).
5. Tasks 2-8 take 1 year.
6. Task 9 comes in, and it only takes 1 second.
7. Task 9 can't be executed because all threads are being used.

Task 1 has code similar to this

```
build_process = subprocess.Popen(build_command, shell=False)
build_process.wait()
```

Is there anyway to grab the Thread from Task1 while it's waiting, and do Task 9? Then when Task 9 finishes go back to Task 1 (waiting for the process to finish?) Does Python already have something like this implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible in basic Python.

What would be possible, although a lot more work than just having a tenth thread, would be to have a queue of things to do, have the main thread stuff things in that queue (so far this is normal), and then have each thread smart enough to know when it's just waiting (for a subprocess to complete, for example) and then take on another task.  Note that I *do not* recommend this approach.  Just create another thread in your thread pool.

If you have a way of knowing which tasks are quick and which are short, then you could make two thread pools: one for long tasks, and one for quick tasks, and assign the task to the appropriate pool's queue.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't event possible in newer versions of Python?

Comment: @Taztingo: Unfortunately not.  Once a thread is started the only support way to manipulate that thread is from inside the thread itself, in which case you may as well just have a tenth thread.